Nginx rewrite document root only - ignore rewrite if get parameter is present
My setup is that i have a subdomain with a wordpress blog (blog.domain.com)
There is another domain for another language that points to the same wp blog (info.domain.uk)
And we habe a domain for our online shop (seconddomain.com)
Problem is, that the second language blog is only for google ads landing pages.
We want to redirect info.domain.uk/ to our shop (only the root)
Two problem is that if a get parameter is present the rewite will redirect me.
Is there a method to ignore the rule if a parameter is present.
Some examples
info.domain.uk/            -> seconddomain.com
info.domain.uk/landingpage -> info.domain.uk/landingpage
info.domain.uk/?ct-builder -> info.domain.uk/?ct-builder
I try it with:
 if ($host ~* info\.(.*)) {
    rewrite ^((?!\?).)*$ https://seconddomain.com permanent; 
    }

But i know if is evil
